# How to call a JavaScript function inside the form_submit?

Tags: forms, javascript

My problem is exactly as the title of my post shows. How should I call a javascript function inside the form_submit hook?

I just need to call a function which is previously defined in a javascript file and and is added to drupal form. How should I call the function?

I have tested submit() event in Jquery. The problem with it is that it starts to be executed as soon as the submit button is pressed.

I need a strategy which can cause the execution of that javascript function INSIDE the form_submit hook, not before it.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: You can't execute javascript on the server side (well, you can, but not in the way you're suggesting)

Comment: Well, you're completely right! I think it would be possible by using an Ajax button and it's callback and using the ajax_command_invoke...   , what do you think?

Comment: Not understanding the use case here. I feel that you've got your logic flow tangled... what does this js accomplish exactly?

Comment: Well, I have found the answer, and I will put it here for everyone to use it.